# jQuery - Intercepting horizontal scrolling & replace with vertical?

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I'm building a vertical website. This has worked itself out very nicely so far, except that now users cannot scroll through the website with their mouse scroll. I'm using jQuery & I'd like to know if there are any ways to intercept horizontal scrolling. My searches so far have turned up results for manually scrolling, but not intercepting them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is :)

```
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    if($(this).scrollLeft()>=0 && $(this).scrollLeft()<=$('body').width())
    var k =  $(this).scrollLeft()-delta*50;     
    $(this).scrollLeft(k)
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! With a bit of tweaking I was able to suit it to my needs completely.

Comment: For anyone interested I thought I would point out that you do need the [mousewheel plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel), which is what froze me up for a bit.